# xcode 5.1.1 - file's owner custom class

Tags: xcode

Please help,

Have recently updated to xcode 5.1.1 - am running OSX 10.8.5

and now in IB, I cannot see or make changes to file's owner class,

when I go to the attributes inspector, I get a "not applicable" message, see attached screen shot.

This is just not occuring to File's owner, any object I click on in IB doesn't show the attributes.

[image]

Comment: You're off by one.  The class name is set on the "Identity Inspector", third icon from the left, Command-Option-3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're viewing the Attributes inspector. You need to look at the Identity inspector, one tab to the right.

[image: Identity inspector]

Comment: It happens. Xcode isn't the most intuitive, especially that side panel.